# Java Lettuce Reactive Pattern - Catch Errors?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm trying to use lettuce instead of Jedis for it's reactive pattern. Jedis can block my vertx eventloop and instead of making it a blocking operation I'd rather have it be reactive.

I can successfully fetch items from redis using lettuce but I haven't figured out how to handle exceptions. As an example-

```
// Attempt A: Is the error in otherstuff?
redis.get(cacheKey).handle((response, otherstuff) -> {
            ...
        }).subscribe();

// Attempt B: Do I add a doOnError?
redis.get(cacheKey).handle((response, otherstuff) -> {
            ...
        }).doOnError((error) -> {
            logger.error(err);
        }).subscribe();

// Attempt C: Do I add my callbacks to subscribe?
redis.get(cacheKey).subscribe((response) -> {
            ...
        }, (err) -> {
            logger.error(err);
        });
```

The first confusion I have is how many ways I can do the same thing. I've found multiple ways to actually get a value, but I've found no way to catch an error. The cache key it's pulling from does not exist, my assumption is that an error would be thrown somewhere.

How do I catch lettuce errors?

Answer (score 0):

The Lettuce reactive client has a subscribe method that you can pass handlers to.

```java
     redisConnection
      .reactive()
      .get("cachekey")
      .subscribe(
        string -> doStuff(string),
        error -> LOGGER.error(error.getMessage())
      );
```